# How to update multiple rows (not ever row) with same value?

Tags: android, sqlite

My table `tbl1` looks like this ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/cca17/3)):

```
id  col1    col2    col3
1   0       1       0
2   1       0       0
3   0       0       1
4   1       1       1
5   0       0       0
```

My requirement is that I get some positive number from the user for each column, and I need to update the rows of a particular column if they contain zero, and finally I should count the number of rows updated and the difference between the user input and the updated count I should add to the last row.

**Let me explain with example:**  
Say user inputs 10 for col1. col1 has 3 rows containing zero so I will update them to 1, and finally the diff i.e. (10 - 3 = 7) I should update in the last row.

After the update I expect the table to look like this:

```
id  col1    col2    col3
1   1       1       0
2   1       0       0
3   1       0       1
4   1       1       1
5   8       0       0
```

```
update tbl1 set col1=1 where id in (select id from tbl1 where col1=0 limit 10)
```

The above query updates all 0s to 1, but how do I add the remaining to last row?

Comment: Why do you have "Sql-Server" as a tag if you want SqlLite?

Comment: If someone helps with SQLite that would be great but I am ok if some people gives me SQL Server query as well, I get the idea with that and then I will try to write it myself

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish your task, I would use 2 update queries. The first one would be the query you already have:

```
UPDATE tbl1 SET col1=1 WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM tbl1 WHERE col1=0 LIMIT 10);
```

I would save the result from the first update query in a variable (since it returns the number of rows affected), and use that result in my next query:

```
UPDATE tbl1 SET col1 = col1+updateResult  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

(`updateResult` is what is returned from the first update query).

I hope this helps.

Comment: SELECT MAX(id)  FROM TABLE may be faster compared to ORDER BY id

Answer (score 0):

First, find out how many rows will be updated:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tbl1
WHERE id IN (SELECT id
             FROM tbl1
             WHERE col1 = 0
             LIMIT 10)
```

The update those:

```
UPDATE tbl1
SET col1 = 1
WHERE id IN (SELECT id
             FROM tbl1
             WHERE col1 = 0
             ORDER BY id
             LIMIT 10)
```

(Without ORDER BY, some random set of ten rows would be updated.)

Then update the last row:

```
UPDATE tbl1
SET col1 = col1 + (10 - ResultFromAbove)
WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id)
            FROM tbl1)
```

To ensure consistency, do everything in a single [transaction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction%28%29).

Comment: Thanks for the solution, will try this and update.. thanks for the pointer to transaction